# first directory not creating using for loop

Tags: shell

Im new to shell scripting. Trying to create directories and moving it to other directory in for loop itself. But first directory i.e 01 is not getting created.

```
year=20017
month=(01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12)
for month in ${month[@]}
do
echo $month
echo "Data importing for $year $month"
echo "Data imported for $year $month"
mkdir "$month"
mv "$month" "$year"
done here
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bash array indexes start from 0, not 1.
So:

```
year=20017
month=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
for month in ${month[@]}
do
  echo $month
  echo "Data importing for $year $month"
  echo "Data imported for $year $month"
  mkdir "$month"
  mv "$month" "$year"
done here
```

**UPDATE**:
You're right:

```
year=2017
months=(jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec)
for m in ${months[@]}
do
  echo $m
done
```

This works because indexes are strings, so `$months` is internally handled as an object, and not an array.

Comment: if I give string then also first directory is not getting created                      ` #!/bin/sh
year=20017
month=(jan feb mar apr may jun july aug sept oct nov dec)
for month in ${month[@]}
do
echo $month
echo "Data importing for $year $month"
echo "Data imported for $year $month"
mkdir "$month"
mv "$month" "$year"
done`

Comment: You'd better start naming your $month scalar variable different from your $month array, at least fo clarity...